# Change data capture in a read-only replica

Tags: sql-server, etl, change-data-capture

I have a SQL Server instance, and a read-only replica of that instance that is used for ETL and analytics pipelines.

The source instance has change data capture (CDC) enabled.

What are best practices around propagating CDC to the replica so that e.g. I can use stored procedures like `cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_customers` to simplify implementation of incremental load processes? It doesn't seem that it propagates automatically. Can one simply enable CDC on the replica, or would that lead to data sync issues where the replica LSNs don't align with the source LSNs?

I assume that simply enabling it would lead to new change data metadata being captured -- would it make sense for me to ignore the CDC metadata in the source database, and only propagate what I receive in the replica?

Comment: Afaik CDC is only, unfortunately, supported on a primary replica.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Stu -- that makes sense. Surely others have had this problem before though -- if the objective is implementing incremental load into a data warehouse, is the solution then to manually copy the tables and objects from the primary and sort of duplicate the functionality of the helper CDC stored procedures on the primary?

Comment: AFAIK, the results of CDC get written into the source (i.e. primary) database. As such, I'd expect read operations against that data to work at a replica. So when you say "it doesn't seem that it propagates automatically", what does that mean?

Comment: I wonder if it works to use watermarks from the primary but data from the secondary.